# Apache Providing Content To Non-SSL Site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, cpanel

**My original site - premium-web-directory.com has NO SSL installed** but the problem is the non-existing domain https://premium-web-directory.com was using the content of https://asknoypi.com. https://asknoypi.com is my main website with valid SSL certificate.

Issue: Since the **non-existing** domain https://premium-web-directory.com has content from https://asknoypi.com, Google indexed it on the search results which leads to duplicate content issues.

**Message** from Hosting Provider:

> When an account has an SSL and dedicated IP, requests for domains on
>   that IP which do not have SSL VirtualHost entries are served using the
>   first SSL VirtualHost entry Apache has in it's configuration file for
>   the related IP. In this case, Apache is returning the content from the
>   "https://asknoypi.com" SSL VirtualHost entry when requesting
>   "https://premium-web-directory.com" since a SSL VirtualHost for
>   "https://premium-web-directory.com" does not exist, and the
>   "https://asknoypi.com" SSL VirtualHost entry is the first one
>   configured ***.

**What I did:**
I tried forcing the non-existent https://premium-web-directory.com to http but *still no luck* since I don't have ssl cert installed on the website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What are the possible steps I can make in order to solve this duplicate content issue? What should I do in order to prevent (https://premium-web-directory.com) from using the content of https://asknoypi.com?

Comment: You're giving Apache directives, but your servers are running nginx (Server nginx/1.12.2). Please start by checking which software you're really using.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is to eventually install a certificate for `premium-web-directory`. Once you have the certificate installed you have multiple options - make your site working over https, do a redirect to http or return 404 - all of them would work properly.

In either case you would also need to have an explicit '**fake**' or '**default**' host catching all requests to inexistent hosts to solve this problem in general. Here's a [related answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/82306/apache-default-catch-all-virtual-host) on how to do it.

> When using name-based virtual hosts, the first virtual host
>   configuration loaded will be the default (Source: [Apache Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CommonMisconfigurations#Not_setting_a_ServerName_in_a_virtual_host.))

The browser would complain on an erroneous certificate in this case - you can't do anything about it, but at least you won't run into the content duplication issue in search engines

This host should produce a meaningful error message or simply return 404. As a more advanced option you can configure it to redirect to `http://` for those hosts not supporting https.

As @Eugène Adell mentioned your sites appear to be using `nginx` - anyway, the solution is [similar](https://serverfault.com/questions/578648/properly-setting-up-a-default-nginx-server-for-https) - you need to mark one of the nginx servers as the [default](https://serverfault.com/questions/329952/how-do-i-set-a-default-host-for-nginx)